# Removing duplicate rows based on a null value

Tags: ssis

We have a SSIS package that does a union all on 2 tables and we need to get rid of duplicate rows if the row is a duplicate and a column value is null.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate component to group by all the columns resulting in a distinct list for you destination

You will also need to use a conditional split to branch the null column away from your target table as follows

[image: Remove duplicates and null records]